# Android iBeacon Component

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ibeacon-android

I am developing a cross-platform beacon app in visual studios for mac (xamarin studios). I have the app pretty much finished, I used the android ibeacon service component.

my problem is the android version ranges the beacons for a couple cycles then my console spits out this for multiple threads.

Thread finished:  #12
[Callback] attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.companyname.gloomygiants/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}

[BluetoothAdapter] stopLeScan()

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothLeScanner] Stop Scan

[BluetoothAdapter] startLeScan(): null

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothLeScanner] Start Scan

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON

[BluetoothLeScanner] onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7 mClientIf=0
Thread started:  #13

Thread finished:  #13

[Callback] attempting callback via intent: 
ComponentInfo{com.companyname.gloomygiants/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}

**Then 20 seconds later after going through 10-15 threads, it restarts the cycles just fine. does anyone have any clues on how to fix this issue?**

Comment: I'm the author of the code you refer to above, but it's not clear what, if anything, is going wrong from that logging information.  It could be normal.  More information on what isn't working correctly for your app when this happens would be helpful.

Comment: My app won't constantly range beacons. So when the app starts it ranges for about 5 seconds then stops and cycles through multiple threads, then 15-20 seconds later it goes back to ranging for another 5 seconds.